# Inductance of composite conductor

Tags: transmission-line, power-engineering

Why L is calculated using average value and not by the formula
1/L = 1/L1 + 1/L2 + ...[image]

Comment: First La ,Lb,Lc etc are calculated assuming no transposition but due to transposition of lines , Inductance of each line will be average of La,Lb,Lc etc and then we can use formula of parllel combination of inductors that you mentioned

Comment: Got it @user215805

Comment: I'm sorry but if conductor X comprises n filaments (i.e. parallel conductors) then no way will the overall inductance be the 1/n x the inductance of one filament. Is your book not considering that the filaments of a conductor are heavily mutually coupled? I mean, formula 2.53 is correct but the words below it are bonkers.

Comment: Expressions of Li's are formed including mutual inductances. Taking mutual inductances separately will give Li = (1/2)*10e-7 Henry/meter ,a constant. The D's in final expression of Lx are because of mutual inductances.